# NodeJS Env Variables undefined when declared in Docker Compose

Tags: node.js, docker

Docker-Compose file

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  backend:
    env_file:
      - secrets.env
    build: .
    container_name: Backend
    ports:
      - 3200:3200
    #command: node -e 'console.log(process.env);'
```

secrets.env

```
MARIADB_USER=root
MARIADB_PASSWORD=password
```

dockerfile

```
FROM node:8-alpine

# set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3200

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

When I logged `process.env.MARIABDB_USER` in nodejs, I am getting back undefined.

When I console.log `process.env` in docker-compose, I got the following output.

```
PiguBackend | { PATH: '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
Backend |   HOSTNAME: '5f85f4475cf8',
Backend |   MARIADB_USER: 'root',
Backend |   MARIADB_PASSWORD: 'password',
Backend |   NODE_VERSION: '8.11.4',
Backend |   YARN_VERSION: '1.6.0',
Backend |   HOME: '/root' }
```

The env variables are being loaded but not accessible in my nodeJS app.

Comment: What base image are you using in your Dockerfile? And what are you using to serve the application?

Comment: @pacuna Updated question with dockerfile

Comment: there's a typo `MARIABDB_USER` and `MARIADB_USER `